Why such a discrepency between tiktoken and vertex count_tokens?
I have been chasing a status 400 response from vertexai for a minute today, ugh. Early in the script i'm using tiktoken to count prompt tokens. The value was ~1.8M, well within Gemini's limit of 2M.
Thought I would use Gemini's count_token method just to check. It came in at 2.07M tokens (would have been so nice to just have gotten a over token limit error message!).
I must be using tiktoken incorrectly because I can't imagine ~200k difference between the two embedding models ("cl100k_base" and whatever gemini uses)...right?
import tiktoken  
from vertexai.generative_models import GenerativeModel

# ---------------------------------------------------

def num_tokens_from_string(string: str, encoding_name: str) -> int:  
    """Returns the number of tokens in a text string."""  
    encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding(encoding_name)  
    num_tokens = len(encoding.encode(string))  
    return num_tokens  

# Trust I have auth and blob client setup here...

user_prompt = await download_blob_as_text(blob_client)

num_tokens = num_tokens_from_string(user_prompt, "cl100k_base")  
logging.info(f'### Number of Tokens in user_prompt: {num_tokens}') # ~1.87M

# Trust I have all the vertex auth, project init, etc. here...

model = GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-pro-001")
response = model.count_tokens(user_prompt)
logging.info(f'### Number of Tokens in user_prompt: {num_tokens}') # ~2.07M

